# Is it true that if $\lim a_n = g$ then $\lim |a_n| = |g|$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, proof-verification

The question is in the title. I'm trying to prove that if $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} a_n = g$ then $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} |a_n| = |g|$. Is the following proof correct?

If $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} a_n = g$ that means that for all $\epsilon > 0$ we have $|a_n - g| < \epsilon$ for sufficiently large $n$. But it is also true that $||a_n|-|g||\leq|a_n-g|<\epsilon$ which means that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} |a_n| = |g|$.

Comment: Your proof is correct.

Comment: Looks fine to me. An alternate proof is available if you have the theorem that if $f$ is a continuous function (such as the absolute value function), then $\lim f(a_n) = f(g)$.

Comment: ^Well, this problem is basically proving that the absolute function is continuous.

Comment: just a little comment: the reciprocally is wrong :-) (just in case)

Answer (score 0):

The proof is correct. The result would also be a consequence of the absolute value being a continuous function.

It is important to note that the converse is not true. That is $\lim |a_n| =|g|$ does *not* imply that $\lim a_n =g$, except for the case $|g|=0$.